Specify keyType when "searching_all_resources" for SA keys with asset_v1 Python client in GCP
I am attempting to utilize python to retrieve all the user-managed service account keys in my organization, with the below snippet from this documentation.
from google.cloud import asset_v1
import google.auth
import json

credentials, project = google.auth.default() 

asset = asset_v1.AssetServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
keys = asset.search_all_resources(
    scope="organizations/<your_organization_number>", 
    query="(createTime > 2024-03-20)",
    asset_types = ["iam.googleapis.com/ServiceAccountKey"], 
    )
for key in keys:
    print(key.display_name) 

The above runs successfully. However, it returns Google provided keys, and does not differentiate user managed keys and Google provided keys in the response from this API call. You can actually validate they are Google provided keys by running the below code snippet:
import os
import google.auth
import googleapiclient.discovery

credentials, project = google.auth.default() 
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build("iam", "v1", credentials=credentials)

keys = (
    service.projects()
    .serviceAccounts()
    .keys()
    .list(name="projects/-/serviceAccounts/<YOUR_SA_WITH_SA_KEYS>")
    .execute()
)
for key in keys["keys"]:
    print(key)

{'name': 'projects/-/serviceAccounts/your_sa.iam.gserviceaccount.com/keys/key0', 'validAfterTime': 'xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ', 'validBeforeTime': 'xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ', 'keyAlgorithm': 'KEY_ALG_RSA_2048', 'keyOrigin': 'GOOGLE_PROVIDED', 'keyType': 'SYSTEM_MANAGED'}
{'name': 'projects/-/serviceAccounts/your_sa.iam.gserviceaccount.com/keys/key1', 'validAfterTime': 'xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ', 'validBeforeTime': "xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ', 'keyAlgorithm': 'KEY_ALG_RSA_2048', 'keyOrigin': 'GOOGLE_PROVIDED', 'keyType': 'SYSTEM_MANAGED'}
{'name': 'projects/-/serviceAccounts/your_sa.iam.gserviceaccount.com/keys/key2', 'validAfterTime': 'xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ', 'validBeforeTime': 'xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ', 'keyOrigin': 'USER_PROVIDED', 'keyType': 'USER_MANAGED'}

Is there anyway to utilize the query parameter to exclude the GOOGLE_PROVIDED keyOrigin values in the search_all_resources call to avoid multiple requests?

I don't know if this is what you are trying to do but you can try using the code below.
import os
import google.auth
import googleapiclient.discovery

credentials, project = google.auth.default() 

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build("iam", "v1", credentials=credentials)
service_account_emails = [
    "<YOUR_SA_WITH_SA_KEYS_1>",
    "<YOUR_SA_WITH_SA_KEYS_2>",
    "<YOUR_SA_WITH_SA_KEYS_3>"
    
]

all_keys = []
for account_email in service_account_emails:
    keys = (
        service.projects()
        .serviceAccounts()
        .keys()
        .list(name=f"projects/-/serviceAccounts/{account_email}")
        .execute()
    )
    all_keys.extend(keys["keys"])

for key in all_keys:
    if key["keyType"] == "USER_MANAGED":
        print(key["name"])


Yeah, thanks for the snippet. Was trying to shave down some time and requests by using Google's "return all sa keys", request.
